# Php: array merge

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am relatively new to php Sorry if I am not asking the question properly. here it goes:

My array:

```
$value = array(
        array('2500'),
        array('3000'),
        array('3500'),
        array('4000')
    );
```

From code:

```
$Array = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($value);$i++) {
    $Array[]=$value;
} 
echo '<pre>';   
print_r($Array);
echo '</pre>';
```

How to merge it into one array like this:

```
Array
    [0] => 2500
    [1] => 3000
    [2] => 3500
    [3] => 4000
)
```

I've tried a lot of codes from array_merge to array_combine nothing seems to do the trick. Is their something I am missing in the code or is there a function or a filter that can accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `sizeof` which can be mistaken for something else make use of `count`.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/lC1g8 Works for me. Though you seem to be inside another look at this for loop only looks around one value?

Comment: The variable $value is outputting like this : 2500300035004000

Comment: Jesus! with all the downvotes i am scared to as questions here.

Comment: What exactly is in `$value`? Your initial code block looks like four separate arrays, rather than one.

Comment: The $value is from advanced custom fields wordpress plugin. its actually a repeter get_sub_field();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$value = array(
        array('2500'),
        array('3000'),
        array('3500'),
        array('4000')
    );

echo '<pre>'; // for display purpose only
print_r($value); // for display purpose only
$array = array();
if (is_array($value)) {
    foreach ($value as $v) {
        $array = array_merge($array,$v);
    }
} else {
    $array = array($value);
}

print_r($array); // for display purpose only
```

EDITED based on OP's update

http://www.phpwin.org/s/ib6dOO

Comment: Yes according to the updated question answer is correct but what if the $value is equal to this 2500300035004000

Comment: Strangely it still outputs this: Array ( [0] => 2500 ) Array ( [0] => 3000 ) Array ( [0] => 3500 ) Array ( [0] => 4000 ), Its like array is embedded into it.

Comment: This is the problem with your question without clear indication of $value. 1) set $array = array before your get_sub_field(); 2) to add the $value to the $array, then use $array = array_merge($array, $value);

Comment: Think I am doing it all wrong. Thanks for your help

Comment: Its a repeater within a repeater and it outputs null :-(

Comment: Hi Michael Eugene Yuen, I got it working using this: $addmore_deadline_cat_fees = array();
if (have_rows('add_more_deadlines')):
while (have_rows('add_more_deadlines')) : the_row();

    $array = array();

    if (have_rows('categories_and_fees')):
    while (have_rows('categories_and_fees')) : the_row();
    
        $array_val = get_sub_field('fee');
    
        array_push($array,$array_val);
    
    endwhile;endif;
    
    $addmore_deadline_cat_fees = array_merge($addmore_deadline_cat_fees, $array);
endwhile;endif;
print_r($addmore_deadline_cat_fees);

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$Array[]=$value;
```

to

```
$Array[]=array_merge($value, $Array);
```

Comment: sorry didnt work output is like this: Array
(
    [0] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
)

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach to iterate through an array.

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array('2500'),
    array('3000'),
    array('3500'),
    array('4000')
);

$output = [];
foreach($data as $value) {
    $output[] = $value[0];
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '2500' (length=4)
  1 => string '3000' (length=4)
  2 => string '3500' (length=4)
  3 => string '4000' (length=4)
```

You could alternatively run a function on each member of the array using array_map. array_pop returns the last element 'popped' off each sub-array.

```
$output = array_map('array_pop', $data);
var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '2500' (length=4)
  1 => string '3000' (length=4)
  2 => string '3500' (length=4)
  3 => string '4000' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$output = array_column($value, 0);
print_r($output);
```