# How to merge dynamic array into one single array in shopify

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

im recieveing an output in the following format.When i foreach the loop only one id is iterated i need to combine these array into one single array so i can iterate all the ids.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6902680092829
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6902680125597
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6902680158365
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6902680223901
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6902680256669
)
```

i want to combine this array into one single array for eg:

```
array:{
0=>1,
1=>2,
2=>3
}
```

im adding shopify product id one by one to an array by doing this

```
$prdid=[];
    array_push($prdid,$shopifyCustomers['body']['container']['product']['id']);
```

Comment: What is the correlation between the current array and the desired output array?

Comment: @BenM THere is no corealtion im just showing how i want the array to be i.e second array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php: array merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035323/php-array-merge)

Comment: @SibiKandathil no array merge is not the solution

Comment: Depending on how you get these arrays, you can take advantage of `collection`, that is why you should be using Laravel and dropping `array_xxxxx` methods (they are used behind scenes). So you can simply do `$collection = collect(...$array1);` and then, when you want to add another ID or whatever, just `$collection->push($id);` and that's it...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```php
$arr1 = [ 6902680092829 ];
$arr2 = [ 6902680125597 ];
$arr3 = [ 6902680158365 ];
$arr4 = [ 6902680223901 ];
$arr5 = [ 6902680256669 ];
$newArr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4, $arr5);
```

Comment: The arrays are dynamically generated and it may have upto 20 different arrays so how can i merge them

Comment: Please add the code, how they are generated to your question.

Comment: You could use the [`splat`](https://www.php.net/splat) operator instead. For example, `$newArr = array_merge(...$oldArr);`